# Xcode project syncing over cloud service

Tags: xcode, git

I'm developing an iOS app on two different Macs. I have a local git repo setup in xcode. Every time I switch Macs, I download the most recent xcode project folder from my backup cloud service, SugarSync. SugarSync automatically uploads any changes I make to the project to the cloud.

Is this unstable, or just simply a bad practice? Is there a better way to build a project on multiple computers for only one developer?

Comment: Is this a closed-source project?  If so, I would worry that my code was exposed to strangers - who knows which people get to see it?

Comment: Yes it's closed source, but who would be able to see it? Are you referring to if it where on GitHub?

Comment: No, just that if it's in a cloud you don't know who gets to see it do you; it's out of your control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using github for something like this. You could push from one machine and pull from the other would would accomplish the same thing you are doing now.

BUT doing what you are doing now should still work, I've done the same with Dropbox in the past.

Comment: Thanks. The only thing that worries me when I use SugarSync for this, is sometimes when I try to make a commit from the main menu, it gives me an error "Cannot find a working copy". When I commit from the organizer, it still works, I'm just worried that something may not have downloaded properly from SugarSync that will throw me wrench later on.

Comment: github would not have this issue, you would just end up with more commits when switching machines. I've also stolen an idea and used before that Rob Connery setup was to make dropbox (or SugarSync) a "remote" in github. So you push to the remote when you are ready to switch machines. When you got to the 2nd machine, you would just pull from the remote which would be SugarSync.